# Converting TimeStamp to String gives character value

Tags: java

I am using this logic but can anyone explain how it works?

Debug value longTimeStamp is `20200212173435`

Debug value stringTimeStamp is `75rukrv5n`

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
Long longTimeStamp = Long.parseLong(timeStamp, 10); 
String stringTimeStamp = Long.toString(longTimeStamp, Character.MAX_RADIX);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing this:

- Getting a `Date` for the current date.
- Formatting it in `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format as a string. That string will contain only decimal digits (0-9).
- Parsing that string of digits as a base-10 (decimal) number, getting that number into a `long`.
- Creating a new string for that number using the highest radix (number base) available for conversions (see: [`MAX_RADIX`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX)).

On my system, for instance, `MAX_RADIX` is 36 (I suspect this is common), which means the "digits" in the number are `0-9` and `a-z`. The number `35` (in decimal) is `z` in base-36. The number `36` decimal is `10` in base-36.

Comment: thanks, I got now it is base-10 to base-36 conversion.